# How to connect old wiring to new light switch?

Tags: electrical

I'm trying to replace an old light switch.  Need help to understand 1) What type of new switch to use, and 2) How to connect with the old wiring.  There are only 2 thick black wires, connected on either side of the switch.  I'd appreciate any advice.  Thanks!

[Photos of old light switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lwcz3.jpg)[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

That is a single pole switch.

You should replace it with the same thing and just put one of the wires on each of the new switch's terminals.

Good luck and stay safe!

Answer (score 1):

New switches will have a **ground screw**, typically a green screw separate from the others.  If you don't have a ground wire in your box, you can disregard this screw - it may ground anyway through the steel box.  (If your house is not grounded, there are other ways to provide the safety of grounds without an expensive re-wire.  Ask.)

So, ignoring that ground screw... you need a plain switch that has **two** screws.  There are a variety of switches on the market, and some switches have 3 or 4.  Those can be made to work, but can also be wired wrong (and then they won't work). Easier (and cheaper) to get the right thing.